# Not able to log the sql server installation progress when running with powershell

Tags: powershell

I am installing SQL Server 2008R2 with Powershell.

Below is the command

```
function install{
$Command ="SQL_SERVER_CDs\SQL2008_R2\R2_ENTERPRISE\Setup.exe /q /ACTION=Install /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /INDICATEPROGRESS /FEATURES=SQLENGINE,REPLICATION,FULLTEXT /INSTANCENAME=DEMO5 /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD=Me@inv2011 /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=CORP\R-PITTUR CORP\AIMFUNDS-G-Admin-SQL /SQLSVCACCOUNT=RAMU-PC\RAMU /SQLSVCPASSWORD=***** /AGTSVCACCOUNT=RAMU-PC\RAMU /AGTSVCPASSWORD=***** /ISSVCACCOUNT=RAMU-PC\RAMU /ISSVCPASSWORD=***** /INSTANCEDIR=S:\\ /INSTALLSHAREDDIR=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server /SQLUSERDBDIR=I:\DB_DATA /SQLUSERDBLOGDIR=H:\DB_LOGS /SQLTEMPDBDIR=T:\DEMO5 /SQLBACKUPDIR=S:\DEMO5 /SQLCOLLATION=SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"

Invoke-Expression $Command 
}
```

When i call this install function, SQL installation is happenening but nothing is displayed in the Powershell console though i put Indicateprogress in the above installation string. How can we display logging of sql server installation. Is it possible to redirect the output to any control like Richtextbox using Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Some of your command options contain spaces, for eg:

```
/INSTALLSHAREDDIR=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server
```

wrap them in quotes like this:

```
`"/INSTALLSHAREDDIR=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server`"
```

note the use of the backtick character (`) to escape the quote within the string.

Answer (score 0):

/q means quite install, right?

Here's the command I use to run SQL 2008 R2 installs:

```
$command += 'setup.exe /CONFIGURATIONFILE=`"$configFile`" /SAPWD=`"$sysadminPassword`" /SQLSVCPASSWORD=`"$servicePassword`" /AGTSVCPASSWORD=`"$servicePassword`" /FTSVCPASSWORD=`"$servicePassword`" /ISSVCPASSWORD=`"$servicePassword`"'

Invoke-Expression $command
```